# how to check time range in javascript

Tags: javascript, time

i have start and end time along with date.like this

```
         stime:1pm , etime:2pm , date:2/6/2013
```

i want to store this start and end time and date into mongodb. so before saving this details

, i should  check within this date, this time range is exist or not

so how to do that in javascript. how to check time range already exist or not?

i have tried like this.but it is not working properly. even i don't know my approach ,whether right or wrong ?

i hope that anyone help me to find solution for this.

```
   var d0 = new Date("01/01/2001 " + "8:30 AM");
   var d1 = new Date("01/01/2001 " + "9:00 PM");
   var d2 = new Date("01/01/2001 " + "8:30 AM");
  var d3 = new Date("01/01/2001 " + "9:00 PM");
 if(d2<d0&&d3<=d0||d2<d1&&d3<=d3)
 {
      console.log("available");
 }else{
     console.log("not available");
 }
```

Comment: Use moment.js (http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: moment-range (https://github.com/gf3/moment-range) extends moment by providing support for ranges

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use timestamp instead of Date object in order to efficiently compare ranges. This as well will be much more efficient for Database to index by timestamp.
If you don't know which of time is earlier in pair of dates for timespans, then you can do `min` and `max` checks. But if you do know which time is before and which after, no `min`, `max` in condition required.
Condition bellow checks if timespans **Overlap** which means it will be `true` even if only last second of first timespan overlaps with first second from second timespan.
You can do other checks for **Contain** and identify which of them contain which, but thats different condition.

```
// time of first timespan
var x = new Date('01/01/2001 8:30:00').getTime();
var y = new Date('01/01/2001 9:30:00').getTime();

// time of second timespan
var a = new Date('01/01/2001 8:54:00').getTime();
var b = new Date('01/01/2001 9:00:00').getTime();

if (Math.min(x, y) <= Math.max(a, b) && Math.max(x, y) >= Math.min(a, b)) {
    // between
}
```

Comment: but i have start and end time to check and also u haven't mentioned am and pm.

Comment: This is one of examples above, to solve your challenge. You can use any valid format of date (with AM/PM or without) as far as it will be properly parsed to actual date by JS. In example above, x is start, and y is end. Additionally it does not matter in example above which date is start and which is end. They are two dates, and range of time will be calculated from them. In most cases it is a scenario.

Comment: Updated the question, to reflect actually the question as before it was slightly different.

Answer (score 3):

i have another solution for that, we can use Moment-range which is plugin for Moment.js

Just check this [Moment Range](https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range) .

```
var start  = new Date(2012, 4, 1);
var end    = new Date(2012, 4, 23);
var lol    = new Date(2012, 4, 15);
var wat    = new Date(2012, 2, 27);
 var range  = moment().range(start, end);
 var range2 = moment().range(lol, wat);

 range.contains(lol); // true
 range.contains(wat); // false
```

Comment: hi pro, demo link is died

Comment: hi @Ryan Nghiem, ok 

but from the above post, one can able to know how moment range works and also i given small scenario . 

If link is died then it doesn't means that answer is not useful

Comment: can you please tell me why some one said answer not useful ,  First you have to visit Moment Range link then you will able to know what is Moment Range and then you can see the example which i defined above