# AngularJS - Is it possible to show data in a specific time range?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-show

hope someone can help me with this question.

I have an entity which contains a start time (let's say 15 o'clock) and an end time (let's say 16 
o'clock). It also contains the date (let's say today^^).

So my query returns all data of today, but I only want to show the data between 15 and 16 o'clock.

Do I need to set a $timeout for each object? Or is it possible to automatically call a method called `shouldShowData` which used in `ng-show`?

Basically I have a list of objects and want to show single object just on a specific time of the day.

**EDIT**
Imagine that the screen is shown in a public place and displays different news at different time (morning news, evening news, ...) and should automatically update when the specific news should be displayed based on it's start and end time. It can't be updated manually with a refresh button for example.

Great to here from you :)

Comment: Maybe you could have a list of objects with an isVisible property i.e. List of myObj { DateToUse = x, isVisible = false }, loop though the list setting the flag and use ng-if or ng-show in the ui. I have done something similar for a complex scenario. Alternatively, the filters (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) are very powerful, but i cannot find a good example to match your request. Sorry it's not a direct answer. If you are setting data in the code behind, you might need to use digest to get it to update the ui.

Comment: Why not to send already filtered data from the server?

Comment: if you are `ng-repeat`-ing over this list, then a `$filter` would work nicely.

Comment: @MajoB: But the server has to sent the actualized data, let's say every minute, because the user want's an actualized list...

Comment: @DavinTryon: Does the filter actualize the list? So let's say the data is visible until 16 o'clock and I was loading the data at 15:55, starring 5 minutes at the screen, doing nothing, will it remove the object from the list at 16 o'clock?

Comment: No, I don't think you'll find functionality like that out of the box.  You could, possibly, send timing events through so that the `$digest` runs.

Comment: @DavinTryon Do you have an example for timing events and $digest? Didn't used it before and don't know what they do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found similar problem and solution for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362240/how-to-check-time-range-in-javascript)

All you need is to wrap this into $filter and use on ng-repeat.

Comment: Yes, with Angular data binding, it will update automatically.

Comment: Now i had time to test it and it works like a charm!
Thank you very much :)